# jQuery plugins conflict

Tags: conflict, mediaelement.js, flexslider

See:

http://global-arts.4pixels.co.uk/global-arts-kingston/events-detail.html

I'm using MediaElement.js for the video at the top of the page and Flexslider for the Slider at the bottom. Both play happily together in desktop browsers, but on iPad and iPhone the video doesn't load and the slider has no images.

Has anyone encountered conflicts that only happen in iOS and is there a way of isolating the two scripts from each other? Similar to noConflict for clashing libraries.

a